# use of "At" and "For" in a sentence

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure

Is use of "at" and "for" in a sentences correct grammatically?

> Fig. 13 shows two lines from hub to casing at upstream and downstream of the rotors and also shows axial velocity distribution **at** the lines **for** Fi=0.275.

<sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

Fi parameter specify amount of inlet velocity in turbine. A part of figure as follows:

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two lines intersect "at" a point.  English considers a point in this sense to be a type of place, and we use *at* to talk about places.  You are correct with *at*.

*X, for { equation }* is well established usage to mean "When { equation } is true/occurs/observed/measured, X*" so this is correct as well.

It is not clear really if you mean *for Fi=0.275* applies to both "two lines from hub to casing at upstream and downstream of the rotors" and "axial velocity distribution at the lines" though.  If it applies to both, you should say

> Fig. 13, for Fi=0.275, shows two lines from hub to casing at upstream and downstream of the rotors and also shows axial velocity distribution at those lines.

or if only to the second statement,

> Fig. 13 shows two lines from hub to casing at upstream and downstream of the rotors and, for Fi=0.275, also shows axial velocity distribution at those lines.